# Array out of bounds but one to early

Tags: java, arrays, for-loop

first heres th code segment.

```
double array [][]= new double [10000][11];

   double test=333;

   array[0][0]=300;
   array[0][1]=400;
   array[0][2]=500;
   array[0][3]=600;
   array[0][4]=700;
   array[0][5]=200;
   array[0][6]=200;
   array[0][7]=200;
   array[0][8]=200;
   array[0][9]=200;
   array[0][10]=200;




   int tiere =0;

   int i=0;

   for (int stelle=0;array[i][stelle]!=0;stelle++){

       tiere++;
   }
   System.out.println(tiere);


   if (tiere<11) test=1;
   else test=array[0][0];

  System.out.println(test);


}
}
```

as you see i show how much used lines the array has and if its 10 it give me that value back. BUT if its 11 so the maximum there is a fail "array out of bounds" whats wrong?

Comment: stare at `array[i][stelle]!=0; stelle++`

Comment: array indexes start at `0` if the array has `11` elements, the last index is `10` and `11` is out of bounds.

Comment: And do you expect that index 11 should be valid and accessible? Why?

Comment: Yes i know but as you can see this is only up to index 10@julekgwa

Comment: Yes and like @julekgwa index 11 is not valid. You also pretend that you know that. So what is unclear here?

Answer (score 1):

You need to change your for loop to only loop valid indexes to avoid your out of bounds error. Then inside the for loop should you put your if check for != 0

```
for (int stelle=0; stelle < array[i].length; stelle++)
{
    if(array[i][stelle] != 0)
    {
        tiere++;
    }
}
```

Comment: @Jim_Beam420 if the answer is good enough to fix your issue, kindly mark it as accepted. stackoverflow.com/help/accepted-answer